# Ideas on how to do near real time chat without using a websocket

Tags: flutter

I am looking for suggestions, I am writing an app using Flutter and AWS Lambda for back end.

One thought I have is to have a back end process looking for undistributed messages, and then sending new ones out via push notifications.

Another thought is client polling (asking once a second if there are new messages for me), but feels data heavy.

Anything else I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at Firebase?  Especially with Flutter, Firebase would give you near-real-time messages across multiple devices and even web (AngularDart).

Comment: Funny that you brought that up, that is exactly what I have chosen to do!
I found the Firebase tutorial code had a ton of old information in it. But the gitter channel for Flutter has been great!